# Client that writes to Server tcpmodel

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, tcplistener

Hi stackoverflow team,

I am creating an application in which I have a server and the client. The server starts the tcplistener. The client connects to the tcplistener and starts writing into the stream.
But the problem that I encounter is once the client writes twice into the stream - it throws non-connected sockets exception.

To illustrate:
Server : starts tcplistener, accept connection to tcp client ( client that writes)
Server starts reading into the stream by method
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

```
     stream obj is used to read the data now from server .
     if(stream.DataAvailable())
       {
        using(StreamReader packetreader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream())
        {
        while(packetreader.Peek() >=0)
         {
         console.WriteLine(packetReader.ReadLine())//content size
         }
        }

         }
```

Client : client connects to the socket and passes stream to NetworkStream object
i.e.,

```
         NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        int packetsize = 0;
     
  while(true)
 {
                 string contentLength = "\r\nContent-Length: {0}\r\n";
                byte[] ContentBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format(contentLength, packetsize));
                NetworkStream.WriteAsync(ContentBytes, 0, ContentBytes.Length);
                NetworkStream.FlushAsync();

 }
```

But in the moment when client reaches Write method second time in the loop it throws non-socket connected exception.

Could anyone state what I am missing out here , is there something logically that I am missing in terms of Client writing to server concept. When I write data from server to client, I do not see that issues.
Also, the error message says unable to write the data to the transport connection. The established connected was aborted by the software in your host machine.

Comment: Could you please show your server side code? It seems your server side to close connection  after first iteration of data transfer.

Comment: Yeah, this looks like the server closing the connection. Would need to see server code.

Comment: @Ryan I have edited and added the server code. I am not closing the connection atleast by calling any api's to close

Comment: @KarthiJayaprakasam, `stream.DataAvailable()` is the wrong approach to check connection state. DataAvailable method only says you that there are data in the host underlying network stack **receive queue**, which are not read by your application yet. Right approach: stream.Read() > 0. If stream.DataAvailable() return false, it only means that next call to `stream.Read` would be a blocking call, i.e thread doing it will be blocked until data received - it does say any related to connection itself.

Comment: ''it does say any related to connection itself'' (C) - does not say, obviously.

Comment: `packetreader.Peek()` - Peek method afaik is not considered a good practice, so just using Read method would be enough and better in context of performance. If this `Peek` exactly that `Peek` i am thinking about).

Comment: @Ryan would usage of those cause the bock of write stream?

Comment: UPD: did not pay attention. Actually, YES, at some point of time, at client side, network stack **send queue** would be overfilled, and any write operations (Socket or TcpClient) would be blocked too. Btw, there is such term as **network deadlock**, when nor sender, neigher receiver are able to do their operations.

Comment: @Ryan Actually apart from namespace and class name and try catch that is the entire code. It always reaches the catch block during the second write. feels weird. Same code runs when i create a new proj and run this code. Thank you very much for detailed explanation , Ryan !!

Comment: You are welcome! Btw, You can reproduce your problem with a minimal code base somewhere in github.